# Windows Phone camera crashes app when switching between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera

I'm creating a simple camera app for Windows Phone 8 in C#. On the main view, the camera is already initialized. There is a button on the main view that takes you to a separate settings page. However, when I press the back button to return to the main page with the camera view, the app crashes and I get this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Unable to acquire the camera. You can only use this class while in the foreground.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

This is the code I use to switch to the settings page:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/settings.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

And on the settings page, I just simply use the back button to return to the main page, which is where the crash happens.

This is the code I use for the camera initialization:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        Size resolution = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back).First();//crashes here
        camera = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, resolution);
        video.SetSource(camera);
        previewTransform.Rotation = camera.SensorRotationInDegrees;
    }
```

The debugger says the app crashes on the 2nd line in that method.

Comment: What is the code that executes when you navigate back to your main page, because i guess that is where your application is crashing. There is no problem in your settings page and you are navigating correctly.

Comment: It just uses the back button to navigate back. Back button navigation is handled automatically by the OS automatically and no specific coding was needed for that. It does successfully return to the main page but crashes when the camera tries to load again. I'll add the camera code to the original post.

Comment: Post the camera initialization code. Also post any code in the page navigation overridden methods

Comment: I have just posted the camera code. I did not override any navigation methods to return to the main page. I only use the automatic back button navigation that's part of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to dispose your camera instance. In the page hosting the PhotoCaptureDevice object:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    camera.Dispose();
}
```